# c++ equivalent to matlab max(find(array < x) and min(find(array > x)

Tags: c++, matlab

what would be the c++ equivalent to this matlab code? I started it off but i'm not sure what value B would be, i think A is correct.

**MATLAB**

```
array = (-1:.001:1)';

    A = max(find(array < 1.0e-2));
    B = min(find(array > 1 - 1.0e-2));
```

**C++ attempt**

```
for(i = 0; i < array.size; i++){
    if(array[i] < 1.0e-2){ 
    k++
    A = k;
   }
    if(array[i] > (1- 1.0e-2)){
    //not sure what to do here
    B = ?;
   }
}
```

Comment: You're more likely to get responses if you describe what you want the code to do, in English, for those of us who don't speak matlab.

Comment: See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/ and in the menu there is min.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I don't really know matlab either nor do i have a copy of it to figure it out myself

Comment: @ToddMoses yeah but theres also a max and find , not just max or just min

Comment: So to understand this post correctly, are you trying to write the max and min function from Matlab into C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second bit, I would do this instead inside the same loop:

```
if(array[array.size-i-1] > (1 - 1.0e-2)) B = array.size - i;
```

and initialize `B` to `array.size` before the loop.

Essentially, you are finding the element with the lowest index in the array which is also larger than `1 - 1.0e-2`. If you start at the element with the highest index and then traverse the entire array and update each time you satisfy the criteria, you will end up with what you need. A similar logic applies for the first part, but you will need to set `A = i+1` instead of incrementing `k` because there is no guarantee the array is sorted.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i = 0; i < array.size; i++){  // Would be faster if you reversed loop direction
    if(array[i] < 1.0e-2)
        A = i;
}

for(i = 0; i < array.size; i++) {
    if(array[i] > 1-1.0e-2) {
        B = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, I just did a max for B instead of min.  Was just a straight fix for the supplied code without being efficient.  Will fix.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the command `A = max(find(array < 1.0e-2));` Is looking for the largest index of the array that is greater than 1.02e-2.

To see how this happens just break down the statement into parts:

`array < 1.0e-2)` returns a vector of logical indices.

`find( ... )` converts the logical indices to numeric indices

`max(...)` returns the largest value from the list of numeric indices.

A C++ equivalent would look something like:

```
int A = -1;
int maxVal = 1.0e-2;
for (int i = array.length-1; i>=0; i--)
   if (array[i] < maxVal){
      A = i;
      break;
   }
```

To get `B` just setup another loop:

```
int B = -1;
int minVal = 1 - 1.0e-2;

for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    if (array[i] > minVal){
        B = i;
        break;
     }
```